# Using jquery to add a value to dynamically created select menu

Tags: jquery, wordpress, loops, dynamic

I am using a [plugin](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/02/converting-jquery-code-plugin/) to create a real slick jquery select (dropdown) menu.

The html requires the following format:

```
<select>
<option value="0" selected="selected" data-skip="1">Choose an Artist</option>
<option value="1">Title</option>
<option value="2">Title</option>
<option value="3">Title</option>
<option value="4">Title</option>
</select>
```

I want to use wordpress to display certain pages in a select menu:

```
<?php wp_dropdown_pages('child_of=96'); ?>
```

Wordpress successfully returns a select menu of all of the correct pages. I need a jquery solution to insert this before the first select element: `<option value="0" selected="selected" data-skip="1">Choose an Artist</option>` and I also need jquery to assign an option value to the next select item (see markup above). So basically, I need a jquery solution to append that line before the first select item and also assign a consecutive option value (i++) to the next select item.

Thanks in advance, and I hope that makes sense.

Comment: this leads to some funky value numbers...let me mess with this. thanks

Comment: when I view the source on that select box I see 5 items starting at 1 and ending at 5. What's wrong?

Comment: it is adding it onto the page id that wordpress assigns. I am working on a new solution. If you write an answer, Ill give it to you....you helped me quite a bit here

Comment: Okay, I'll make an answer, however I've never used Wordpress, so I can't begin to debug that part of the problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `prepend` your new list option to your `select` and then loop over the `options` and insert `value` attribute with a number that increases each time the function loops.

```
    $("select").prepend("<option selected='selected' data-skip='1'>Choose an Artist</option>'");
       var i = 1;
    $("select option").each(function() {
       $(this).attr("value",i);
       i++;
     });
```

Fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/67de7/1](http://jsfiddle.net/67de7/1)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can uniquely identify your select field (e.g. id or class name) something like this should do what you want:

```
var select = $('select'); // Or according selector
select.prepend('<option value="0" selected="selected" data-skip="1">Choose an Artist</option>');
$('option', select).each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr('value', index);
});
```

Basically the last loop sets the value of each option of the select field to it's index.

Comment: the option value has to be 1, and then 2, and 3 and so on. The jquery solution needs to accommodate adding +1 to each consecutive select item.

Comment: Then add 1 to the index or use $(this).attr('value', $(this).attr('value') + 1). Otherwise it seems to work exactly like the jsFiddle example in the questions comments